# Change VM options generte a error

Tags: intellij-idea, jvm, virtual-machine, size, heap-memory

I changed vm options and add Xxs16m , now when i try open idea.sh i have this error in console.

Unrecognized option: -Xxs16m
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: Did you want to change the stack size using the `-Xss` option or the heap size using `-Xms` option? There is no `-Xxs` JVM option.

Comment: yes, i need delete Xxs options but i cant find this line.

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869. The file is in your home directory.

Comment: I use this "Help | Edit Custom VM Options menu" for add Xxs. I try modify idea64.vmoptions or idea.vmoptions in "idea-IC-171.4424.56/bin/"   but Xxs is not in files.

Comment: Yes, because it's in your home directory, not in bin, read the article carefully.

Comment: Ty, i found it.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, there's no such option as `-Xxs[size]`. I'm guessing you meant to configure the minimal heap size, which would be `-Xms16m`.

Comment: yes, there's not option and i need delet this line but i cant open ide. I add this line from ide

Answer (score 0):

-Xxs is not the right option, either you should use.

```
1. -Xss - sets the thread stack size
2. -Xms - sets th initial and minimum Java heap size
3. -Xmx - sets the maximum Java heap size
```

Regarding other options find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html)